# flatMap typing - attempting to merge DoubleStreams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

```
    final double[][] a = new double[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
    final int numRows = a.length;
    final int numCols = a[0].length;
    final double[] da = IntStream.range(0, numCols)
            .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, numRows).mapToDouble(j -> a[i][j])).flatMap(d -> d)
            .toArray(double[]::new);
    // da should be [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Error is:  Cannot infer type argument(s) for  flatMap(Function>)

What is the correct way to write this?  I have tried emitting double[] from the map but can't get that to go either.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

There is a little bug in your code: you mixed `i` and `j` in `a[i][j]`.
Changing these indices you get it with:

```
double[] da = IntStream.range(0, numCols)
    .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, numRows).mapToDouble(j -> a[j][i]))
    .flatMapToDouble(d -> d)
    .toArray();
```

Instead `flatMapToDouble(d -> d)` you also may use `flatMapToDouble(Function.identity())`.

Comment: Ah - flatMapToDouble - that's what I was missing.  Thanks guys - awesome!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this as well:

```
final double[][] a = new double[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
final double[] da = Arrays.stream(a)
    .flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream)
    .toArray();
```

It makes a stream of streams and then flat maps it. Advantage of this is that you can have any size nested array.

Note: as Alexis C pointed out it doesn't interleave the elements. You will get the result in the order the elements were in the original array. E.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: Note that this does not interleave the elements as the OP requires. By the way, you can make it a bit shorter with `Arrays.stream(a).flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream).toArray();`

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that. Edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick :

```
final double[] da = IntStream.range(0, numCols)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, numRows).mapToDouble(j -> a[j][i])).flatMapToDouble(d -> d)
        .toArray();
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 5.0, 3.0, 6.0]
```

Note that `flatMap` didn't work since it expects to map your intermediate `Stream<DoubleStream>` to a `Stream<SomeReferenceType>`, which is not possible with your mapping function.

Using `flatMapToDouble` would transform the `Stream<DoubleStream>` to a `DoubleStream`, which can be easily converted to a `double[]`.